# Command Line Arguments in DNSlookup

Tags: python, nslookup, dig

I'm trying to check reverse lookup of IP address and then write the result to txt file. But I don't know how can I get the IP address as command line argument (Linux environment) instead of write the IP inside the script.

My script:

```
import sys, os, re, shlex, urllib, subprocess 

cmd='dig' -x 8.8.8.8 @192.1.1.1

proc = subprocess.Popen(shlex.split(cmd), stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
out, err = proc.communicate()

sys.stdout = open("/tmp/test.txt", "w")
print(out)
sys.stdout.close()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get cli arguments with `sys.argv`:

```
import sys, subprocess 

cmd = 'dig -x %s @192.1.1.1' % sys.argv[1]

proc = subprocess.Popen(cmd.split(), stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
out, err = proc.communicate()

with open("/tmp/test.txt", "w+") as f:
    f.write(out)
```